# Trying to get property 'times' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is a strange one (for me at least), I'm trying to pass an object to a function like so:

```
272.  $runs[$key]['position'] = getTimePosition($run->times,$user['id']);
273.  dd($run->times);
```

When I do it I get the error

```
message: "Trying to get property 'times' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\Users\Test\PhpstormProjects\test\app\Helpers\Helper.php"
line: 272
message: "Trying to get property 'times' of non-object"
```

However, if I dump $run->times I get what seems to be correct, an Eloquent object with "times" as shown below...

What am I missing here? It's been bugging me for an hour

[image]

Comment: The attribute name is time, not times

Comment: Also, if `$run->times` value is an eloquent collection instance, you can not access to a model attribute directly. You'll should iterate over and get the attribute for each model, or get just one model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I guess your result set return multiple rows so that you need to iterate them by using the loop or you can get the result by using.
 `$run[0]->time`

If you want to get a single row from DB you should use it.

```
    $run = DB::table('tableName')->where('condition')->first();
    $run->time
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute name is $run->time, not $run->times

```
$runs[$key]['position'] = getTimePosition($run->time,$user['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
if($run) {
    $runs[$key]['position'] = getTimePosition($run->times,$user['id']);
}
```